# Django Forms Default Select Value in Front of Dynamic Loop

Tags: python, django, forms

Trying to add a default choice `('', 'Select Type')` in front of dynamic select loop that is in place and working.

**form.py**

```
card_choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in Payment.objects.filter(id=id)]
payment = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Type', choices=card_choices)
```

**template.html**

`{{ form.payment }}`

will generate this:

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">VISA</option>
<option value="2">Amex</option>
<option value="3">Mastercard</option>
<option value="4">Discover</option>
```

Looking for:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Type</option>
<option value="1">VISA</option>
<option value="2">Amex</option>
<option value="3">Mastercard</option>
<option value="4">Discover</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this value on first place in choices tuple:

```
payment = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Type',
                            choices=[(None, 'Select Type')]+card_choices)
```

Comment: wouldn't this raise `TypeError`? `card_choices` is a list

Comment: Thank you! I was close when I was trying but I guess my mistake was using `''` instead of `NONE` :)